# Flatten a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

I want to flatten the JSON so that the values of columns can be obtained even if it's a nested JSON.

This is the JSON file :

```
"columns": {
    "id": {
      "$type": "pyint"
    },
    "name": {
      "firstname": {
        "$type": "pystr",
        "$props": {
          "min_chars": 10,
          "max_chars": 20
        }
      },
      "lastname": {
        "$type": "pystr",
        "$props": {
          "min_chars": 10,
          "max_chars": 20
        }
      }
    },
    "price": {
      "$type": "pyfloat",
      "$props": {
        "right_digits": 2,
        "positive": true
      }
    }
}
```

The output should be like:

```
{id:pyint  , firstname:pystr   , lastname:pystr ,  price:pyfloat}
```

The data structure to store doesn't matter as long as the correspondence between the items is maintained.

Comment: if you want to load the json into dictionary you can try
`json_data=open(file_path).read()`
`data = json.loads(json_data)`
data is dictionary containing the json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function that recursively looks for the `'$type'` key in sub-dicts:

```
def recurse(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if '$type' in v:
                yield k, v['$type']
            yield from recurse(v)
```

so that assuming your JSON object is loaded into variable `d`, `dict(recurse(d))` would return:

```
{'id': 'pyint', 'firstname': 'pystr', 'lastname': 'pystr', 'price': 'pyfloat'}
```

Comment: This works. For python3, yield from recurse(v) needs to be replaced with 
for res in recurse(v):
     yield res